# Change date format dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: vba, date

The data source is a txt file that uses the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Dates are populated in two columns: N and O. The desired output is to have all dates in these two columns reformatted to `mm/dd/yyyy`

txt file:

```
N           O
05/12/20    14/05/2020
```

So far I have the following code:

```
Sub Format_Dates()
Range("N:N").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"

Range("O:O").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
End Sub
```

The code does not work for days between 13 and 31.

Appreciate any input. THX

Comment: Can you add the relevant language tags? I assume VBA or VB.NET?

Comment: It's VBA, sorry, am very new to the game

Answer (score 0):

Why have you put only two y? It should be "mm/dd/yyyy":

```
Range("N:O").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

First consider the regional settings of your system. Because you can get a mess if you get `11/10/2001`, what date would be right? `Thursday, October 11, 2001` or `Saturday, November 10, 2001`? That is up to you.

With this disclaimer proceed:

```
Sub formatDate()
    'dd/mm/yyyy
    'to
    'mm/dd/yyyy

    Dim str As String 'your string with the date this way: dd/mm/yyyy
    Dim D 'to days
    Dim M 'to months
    Dim Y 'to years

    str = "11/10/2001" 'dd/mm/yyyy
    D = CInt(Left(str, 2)) 'Need to cast this "11" to this 11.
    M = CInt(Mid(str, 4, 2))
    Y = CInt(Right(str, 4))

    Dim DD As Date 'define the vas as a Date to tell the system to use the regional setting of dates
    DD = DateSerial(Y, M, D) 'Now we just need to insert the values inside DateSerial as the function need
    Range("N1").Value = DD 'Send the value to the cell you need, here I use N1

    'Range("N:N").NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy" 'Use the format you want. I like this.

    Range("N:O").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 'This is your format. Both columns 
End Sub
```